# Vector space of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

What does the vector space of $M_{m \times n}$ really mean? Is it both the row space and the column space of $M$ together?

If I only look at the column space, I would say that a basis for the columspace would be a $1\times n$ matrix (assuming $n$ linearly independent column vectors). Similarly a basis for the row space would be $m\times 1$ matrix. Is this right? How do I find the basis for the $m\times n$ matrix?

Comment: Row rank = column rank

Comment: The question from the task that motivated this question is simply "Find a basis for the vector space ${\cal M}_{m\times n}$. I'm confused about that what they really mean here

Comment: A matrix can be multiplied by a scalar, and two matrices can be added together. This means that the set of all matrices of the same size form a vector space. The vector space of matrices is unrelated to the row or column space of a fixed matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means the collection of all $n \times m$ matrices. This set equipped with the sum and multiplication by scalar is a vector space.
Then comes the question of how one can characterize an element in $M_{m \times n}$. To do this you will need to find a basis of $M_{m \times n}$, a set of independet matrices in  $M_{m \times n}$ that generate $M_{m \times n}$. In this way if one gives you a set of numbers (coordinates with respect to that basis) you can build from that the corresponding matrix in $M_{m \times n}$. Intuitively since an $m \times n$ matrix will have $mn$ entries you will need $mn$ numbers that will be the coefficents of a linear combination of the elements of your basis. A basis of $M_{m \times n}$ is commonly the set of all matrices with only one element set to $1$ and everything else set to $0$. For example 
$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2\\ 
3 & 4
\end{pmatrix} = 
1\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
+ 2
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\ 
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
+ 3
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\ 
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
+ 4
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\ 
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$

The column (row) space of a matrix is a different thing, it's the set of all the linear combinations of the columns (rows) of your matrix.

Comment: So I would end up with $mn$ matrices starting with 1 in the first position, 0 everything else, then moving on to second position and so on? It seems a bit clunky to write all this out, is there a way to generalize the basis in a single matrix for instance?

Comment: Because $mn$ is the dimension of $M_{m \times n}$ (the number of the elements of a basis of $M_{m \times n}$) you will always need $mn$ matrices to fully specify any $M \in M_{m \times n}$. Furthermore the way you give a matrix is by specifying its entries i.e. the coefficients of the linear combination of the matrices of the canonical basis I mentioned above. Surely you can choose a different basis, but its cardinality won't change.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thank you for the assistance sir. This is a little bit off topic, but just so I don't have to open another thread: Could you also clarify what the notation ${\cal C}^n(\mathbb{R})$ means? Still in the context of vector spaces

Comment: Usually notation is defined before being used, so what you should do is quote the definition, or at least an example of its usage (possibly in a new thread, but this is up to you)